# how to use "%s" with Tex-renderer

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, latex

I want do use LaTex-signs in my matplotlib-figure. First I used.

```
pl.ylabel(r'$\pi \rho$',family='Courier New')
```

That was ok. But now the label I want to use is variable and comes from other *.py file. My idea was to import this file to the file from where the title comes:

```
import plot
YLabel = "$\pi \rho$"
plot(YLabel)
```

and in plot.py write:

```
pl.ylabel(r'%s' %(YLabel),family='Courier New')
```

But this Error appears:

```
ValueError: 
$\pi$ $
ho$
      ^
Expected end of text (at char 6), (line:1, col:7)
```

I already read [Text rendering With LaTeX](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html) and [Writing mathematical expressions](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/mathtext.html) from the docs of matplotlib, but it didnt help me.

Comment: The escaping is not nesting like you think it is.

Comment: As it seems adding another "\" solves the problem...  "YLabel = "$\\pi \\rho$"... but I dont understand why.

Comment: You need the `r` when defining the `YLabel` string if you want to avoid escaping. It's not the string interpolation (`%`) that's going wrong, it's the initial definition of `YLabel`.  `"\r"` is a carriage return, so if you want to type a literal "\r" in python, you need to do either `r"\r"` or `"\\r"`.  That's why you'll see the leading `r` (for raw string) before many regex expressions and matplotlib mathtex expressions.  Otherwise you have to escape any "\t", "\n", "\b", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening actually has nothing to do with the string formatting (i.e. calling `x = "blah %s" % YLabel`).

It's due to the way you initially define `YLabel`.

For example, try doing:

```
x = "\rho"
print x
```

The `"\r"` is interpreted as a carriage return and doesn't print. It just prints "ho".  (This holds for [a number of other escape sequences, e.g. `\n`, `\t`, `\x`, `\f`, `\b`, etc.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals))

To avoid this, you either need to define the original string as a "raw" string:

```
x = r"\rho"
print x
```

or explicitly escape the `"\r"` sequence:

```
x = "\\rho"
print x
```